# LUIS API - High latency on the publish endpoint

Tags: api, nlp, latency, azure-language-understanding

I am currently working on a project in which I am **automating LUIS application creation**.
The injection of intentions and entities goes smoothly, as does the training of the model. I do not observe high latency on these endpoints.

However, the **publishing step using API V2 takes a lot of time**, much more than publishing with the web interface.
This step can take a few minutes but at the end I do have a Success status code and the application is published well.

So I was wondering if the highy latency on the publish endpoint problem is widespread or if it comes from my side.

Is there anything I can do to **reduce latency on the publish endpoint** using API V2 ?

EDIT:
My application/model has 3 intents with about 80 utterances and 4 entities in total.

---

***Thank you by advance.***

Comment: Can you describe your model? number of intents, number of utterances, number of entities, etc?

Comment: @DFBerry I edited my post to add these numbers.

Comment: If this issue is consistent, you always have latency on publish, consider using LUIS website support to ask for clarification on how to increase speed through API. If this is randomly happening, not sure.

Comment: Is the issue still persistent?

Comment: I have no explanation, but latency seems to have decreased in the last few days. There is still some, but much less.